# /python/ из pandas.DataFrame в json

Tags: javascript, python, json, pandas

Подскажите элегантное решение передачи данных и pandas.DataFrame на клиента.

Проблема в том, что javascript не может распарсить float('nan') который используется в pandas вместо None ( так же проблема с date('nan') )

**пример:**

python:

```
    import pandas
    import json
    frame = pandas.DataFrame([{'one':1.0,'two':2.0},{'one':float('nan'),'two':3.0}])

    # >>> frame
    #    one  two
    # 0  1.0  2.0
    # 1  NaN  3.0

    # >>> frame.T.to_dict().values()
    # [{'two': 2.0, 'one': 1.0}, {'two': 3.0, 'one': nan}]

    json_frame = json.dumps( frame.T.to_dict().values() )

    # >>> json_frame
    # '[{"two": 2.0, "one": 1.0}, {"two": 3.0, "one": NaN}]'
```

js:

```
    json_frame = '[{"two": 2.0, "one": 1.0}, {"two": 3.0, "one": NaN}]'
    // "[{"two": 2.0, "one": 1.0}, {"two": 3.0, "one": NaN}]"
    JSON.parse(json_frame)
    // SyntaxError: Unexpected token N(…)
```

сейчас использую:

```
frame.where((pandas.notnull(frame)), None)
```

но хотелось бы pandas сказать что бы он по дефолту не использовал nan а выставлял None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Менять данные при смене формата – плохая идея, поэтому Pandas так не умеет.

Самый простой способ – руками заменить `nan` на `None`. Это можно сделать так: `frame.fillna(0)`. Или так: `frame = frame.where((pd.notnull(frame)), None)` (в предложенном варианте так и есть, это хороший вариант).

В документации Pandas есть классный [раздел про работу с отсутствующими данными](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html), советую прочитать.